# entrez python api urllib2.URLError

Tags: python, api

I want to use Entrez API in Python to grab some informations from Pubmed,this is just a example of Official Tutorial.

```
Entrez.email = "example@xx.com"     # Always tell NCBI who you are
handle = Entrez.einfo()
record = handle.read()
print record
```

This is just a simple example.But sometimes I encounter this error,and don't know how to deal with it.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rabbit/PycharmProjects/test_2.7/Biopython.py", line 25, in <module>
    handle = Entrez.einfo()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/biopython-1.66-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 258, in einfo
    return _open(cgi, variables)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/biopython-1.66-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 516, in _open
    handle = _urlopen(cgi)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 65] No route to host>
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 65] No route to host>
```

I never used Entrez but the above error indicates that `urllib2` is unable to connect to the host. So check whether you have an active internet connection or your are offline.

Comment: I have checked my internet connection,I can view webpages in browser,does this indicate that the internet connection has no problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a limit set by NCBI API. They have a guideline for using the API. Please check that you aren't exceeding the limit. If you hit that limit, this error will occur regardless of your internet connectivity.

If you have >300 requests get a custom API key from NCBI. You can do that by signing up to NCBI website.

Also, if you are using this script to download files, it's better to use efetch() rather than einfo().

To avoid the network error related stop, I've been recommended to use the "try and except" functions in python.

Such as

```
    try:
        net_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=id_list[ax], rettype="fasta", retmode="text")
    except (IOError):
           do something to manage the error/move on to next step
```

It hasn't been a foolproof solution but it works most of the time.